# Running a GTK+ application built with MSYS2 by just double clicking it

Tags: c, windows, dependencies, gtk, msys2

I have a [simple window](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5) application, built with [MSYS2](http://msys2.org), which I want to be able to run outside of the MSYS2 MinGW shell, just by double-clicking on the application.

The problem is that when I want to run the application it must be  though the `MSYS MinGW` prompt otherwise it returns an error.

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libgio-2.0-0.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem
```

I tried including (by copying the files to the location of my exe)
`libgio-2.0-0.dll` and more errors appeared saying libraries were missing.  I included those files too.  I have shown the files I included below:

```
libffi-6.dll
libgdk-3-0.dll
libglib-2.0-0.dll
libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
libgtk-3-0.dll
libgobject-2.0-0.dll
libgio-2.0-0.dll
libatk-1.0-0.dll
libcairo-gobject-2.dll
libcairo-2.dll
libepoxy-0.dll
libpcre-1.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll
libpango-1.0-0.dll
```

In the end an error appears saying:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).  Click OK to close the application.
```

[I found what the error message means:](https://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-solve-the-0xc000007b-unable-to-start-error/)

> That particular error code refers to an invalid image format. However, what the error code usually means is that you are trying to run a program that is intended to work with a 64 bit Windows operating system, but that you only have a 32 bit OS.

However it does not help as I am running an x64 computer.  The DLL are x64 as well as the exe.

[www.gtk.org](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) says GTK+ depends on some libraries and apart from what I have done above I cannot think of any solution and cannot find any documentation on what dependencies to include in order to not run it through the MSYS prompt.

So what do I need to do to get my window working?  The application is fine there is a problem with the dependencies.

Secondly what are the dependencies I need to include (or have I listed all of them in which case what is going wrong with my window)  for the script I gave?

And finally is there an easier way than what I am trying to do to get all the necessary dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system needs to be able to find the shared libraries. On a Linux system, this is through the linker, usually `ld`. The configuration for where to find them lies in `/etc/ld.so.conf` and `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

Now on Windows, this doesn't exist. That's why the environment variable `PATH` commonly is used for that, and sometimes modified by installers. But changing the `PATH` for every program is annoying and forbids relocation (moving the whole app directory and running the app from elsewhere). So you may just create an empty directory, create a `bin` directory in it, and copy your application binary and the GTK+ libraries there. That should work because [the current directory is searched before the `PATH` variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) on Windows.

So what you have done is correct. The problems you have are similar to app redistribution, ie. gathering the necessary bits to distribute a software on another computer. This isn't the most documented part on the GTK+ website unfortunately. Have you tried with a an application that doesn't use the `GtkApplication` class?

Comment: As an experiment I copied the entire contents of the `bin` folder with my application.  Double clicked on it and the window opened.  An error message appeared on the console screen but the window did open.  Then I removed all exe and it still worked.  And then all the dll except for the ones I mentioned above.  It returned the same error.  This leads me to believe a dll is missing.  There is also an error saying `Could not find the icon 'window-minimise-symbolic-ltr'.  The hicolor theme`  any idea how to fix this?

Comment: OK yeah any idea which DLL is missing?

Comment: Use the `pacman` package manager to list the files included in the GTK+ package.

Comment: What command do I use?  This might be the answer to my problem.

Comment: I just don't get the `pacman` commands, they're a pain in the *ss to remember. Search some pacman tutorials or read `pacman --help`. But this is a feature provided by all package managers.

Comment: I have solved the DLL problem.  Using the [Linux](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/409/how-to-list-shared-library-dependencies-used-by-an-application/) command `ldd` you can list all an application's dependencies.  I typed `ldd myapp` in the Msys MinGW 64-bit shell and it returned a long list of all the necessary dependencies.  I copied those in manually from `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin ` and the Window opened.

Comment: I still have an icon problem with the window.  The Maximize, Minimise and Close icons do not appear.  @liberforce I thought it was just me with problems remembering the Msys commands though (HeHe).

Comment: Right  I solved the icon problem.  I created a new file where my exe is located named `share`.  Next I created a sub folder called `icons` and copied `hicolor` from the file location: `C:\msys64\mingw64\share\icons` into it and they appeared. : )

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by including library through **command line** like this.

gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-1 example-1.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

and run it using **mingw64.exe** that comes with  [MSYS2 installer](http://www.msys2.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the point of my question was that I cannot run my executable outside of the MSYS shell: "The problem is that when I want to run the application it must be though the MSYS MinGW prompt otherwise it returns an error.", I want to run this executable just by double clicking it, without going through the MSYS prompt..

Comment: i tried to run standalone app but the gtk 3.0.dll is missing when we compile it using --libs command it binds them but i think we still need that **gtk.dll** to run it.

Comment: Yeah I heard it was (almost) impossible not to include the DLL as well.  One way I did it (above) was to use `pacman` to list all dependencies and add/link all the DLLs to the same folder, makes a large executable though.

Comment: Yes.  Running through the `packman` ordeal just to test the output would be fatal.